# Requiring password even when logged in for certain resources in Spring Boot webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

There is plenty of documentation online for how to secure Spring webapps and microservices, but I haven't found a way to add an extra password request for a few limited pages in an app.

For example, Amazon knows who I am and I can buy something with one-click from my laptop. But if I want to look at my account page, I have to log in.

How can I have multiple levels of user access in my Spring Boot app, with different expiry for each level? Do I need to apply this to the microservices that back my app, as well?

Comment: setting the cookie `JSESSIONID`  for special path(except the certain resource) maybe is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security has fine-grained configuration support per resource, so you can add your custom authentication manager to challenge user once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring custom security and configure some endpoints which needs to pass the spring security authentication and some you can configure to be invoked without authentication check.

you can extend AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter of spring security and override the requireAuthentication method of the above filter to configure which endpoint you want to skip authentication.

```
     protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,      HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (request.getRequestURI().toLowerCase().contains("ToBeSkipped")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to completely skip authentication/authorization. For the vast majority of resources, the user should be authenticated, but it can come from a long-term cookie. For a few select pages, I want the user to have to enter their password again.